# How can I get the modulus to a certain range and then ignore all terms above a certain value

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, piecewise-continuity

I have a modulus below, how can I ignore all values above 1, so there are essentially "spaces" or discontinuous regions.

[image]

[image]

My goal is to create a triangle wave that follows a zigzag pattern between 0 and 1, with an interval of `n*pi` in the same form as two x-inverted modulus functions cut off at `y >= 1`, as seen below: **Essentially I want to make this graph with a single formula:**

[image]

I could technically do this with a piecewise function but in this scenario I specifically cannot use them:

[image]

Comment: In the last question you asked, I suggested $f(x) = |(x \pmod{2})-1|$.  This is a $2$-periodic function which, so far as I can tell, gives you what you want.  If there is a problem with the period or amplitude or phase or whatever, there are standard transformations for adjusting these things, e.g. $2f(2x/\pi)-1$ will be $\pi$-periodic, will have amplitude $2$, and will be "centered" on the $x$-axis.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vivx43tosp

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes thats exactly what I want, thanks, can you put that into an answer?